# Expression language in access control security.yml not for routing

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

I have a problem with using parameters in access control *(symfony 3.3.*)* :

```
-
    path: ^/api
    allow_if: "has_role('ROLE_API_USER') or request.getHost() in '%internal_host%'"
```

**stack trace error** :

```
A string value must be composed of strings and/or numbers, but found parameter &quot;internal_host&quot; of type array inside string value &quot;has_role('ROLE_API_USER') or request.getHost() in '%internal_host%'&quot;
```

I tried other way like `request.getHost() in parameter('internal_host')` or `request.getHost() in container.getParameter('internal_host')` but i have errors message like `The function &quot;parameter&quot; does not exist around position 51 for expression has_role('ROLE_API_USER') or request.getHost() in parameter('internal_host').` (The same message for container service).

***How can i use parameters in access control with expression language?***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access global parameters from route condition expressions in Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606836/access-global-parameters-from-route-condition-expressions-in-symfony)

Comment: not duplicate this is for security access_control not for routing and i already tried and not successfull

Comment: anny solution bro !

Answer (score -1):

If you use Symfony 3 you can try :

```
-
    path: ^/api
    allow_if: "has_role('ROLE_API_USER') or request.getHost() in ['%internal_host%']"
```

cf [Access global parameters from route condition expressions in Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606836/access-global-parameters-from-route-condition-expressions-in-symfony)

Comment: yes i have already tried this but not work because of %internal_host% that is a parameter

Comment: Have you try to use [env parameter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html#environment-variables) ? I think it can be used for an internal host

Comment: I have the same error :  
The function &quot;env&quot; does not exist around position 51 for expression `has_role('ROLE_API_USER') or request.getHost() in env('internal_host')`

Comment: Did you find any solution ??